# Why are there two active links?

Tags: html, css, linked-list

I have an unordered list:

```
<ul>
    <a href="#frame-1"><li>Rogue</li></a>
    <a href="#frame-2"><li>Listen</li></a>
</ul>
```

and have styled it this way:

```
a {
color: grey;
text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
text-decoration: underline;
}

a:active {
text-decoration: underline;
}
```

I've tried to set it so that the link is only underlined when it's hovered over (it does that) and when it's active. However, both links are underlined after they are clicked. Does that mean both are active? How do I get it to only underline the last link clicked (the active one)?

Comment: Define your anchor tag  a{text-decoration:none;}

Comment: But isn't that the first thing I did? a{color: grey; text-decoration:none;}

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is not correct.

try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kiranm/sn1omj4q/2/)**

```
<ul>
   <li> <a href="#frame-1">Rogue</a></li>
   <li> <a href="#frame-2">Listen</a></li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
    $("a").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("a").addClass("active").not(this).removeClass("active");
    });
});
```

Comment: Hmm..now the active links don't get underlined at all. This is very strange.

Comment: Is javascript really the only way to fix this? I would've thought plain CSS could handle this.

Comment: You need js for click event.. if you need with css.. just use "active" class for anchor tag, but manually you need to change according to the page selected.

Answer (score 0):

first of all the HTML structure is in correct. You should include a element inside the li element. Which will produce this:

**Your HTML:**

```
<ul>
   <li> <a href="#frame-1">Rogue</a></li>
   <li> <a href="#frame-2">Listen</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Your CSS** does not need to be changed, apart from:

```
a:active, {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Needs to also include the new `.active` element we will be using so just add a `,` to apply it to multi classes/ids.

```
a:active,.active {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

**Your JavaScript**
Now to make the magic work you should use some JavaScript for this I will be using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), a JavaScript library.

```
$(function () {
    // This detects if click any HTML element inside <a></a>
    $("a").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // This will apply the a:active if it is clicked, else if not active remove class.
        $("a").addClass("active").not(this).removeClass("active");
    });
});
```

Now if we add all that together and include the reference to the jQuery library you will have the following code, you choose how to septate it through your file layout:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(function () {
    // This detects if click any HTML element inside <a></a>
    $("a").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // This will apply the a:active if it is clicked, else if not active remove class.
        $("a").addClass("active").not(this).removeClass("active");
    });
});
</script>

<style>
a {
color: grey;
text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
text-decoration: underline;
}

a:active,.active {
text-decoration: underline;
}
</style>

<ul>
   <li><a href="#frame-1">Rogue</a></li>
   <li><a href="#frame-2">Listen</a></li>
</ul>
```

This will effectively achieve what you are trying to do, let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: I feel dumb now because I am having issues. I changed the a element as you've indicated and I've tried plugging in the JS code at the beginning of the body, at the end, and also in the header. It still doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: In this solution use `a.acitve{text-decoration:underline;}` instead of  `a:active{text-decoration:none;}`

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot to add the .active to the css. Instead of replacing it I have simply added it to the same css class.

Comment: Also @ReotheNew make sure you are not using multiple jQuery libraries as that normally causes issues for me. But once you use my adjusted code that should work fine for you without any more issues.

Comment: It works [my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qhmpx7og/), but not via my actual files. I think perhaps the problem is my implementation of javascript. I can't seem to figure out what's causing the problem. I copied the javascript and pasted it in multiple spots around my html, but it hasn't worked thus far. The problem seems to lie there and I can't quite track it down.

Comment: Ok, I used jQuery 10.1.0 and that helped. Now though, the link is underlined when it's active, but it doesn't actually go anywhere anymore. Does the javascript stop it from acting as a link?

Comment: @ReotheNew Shouldn't be an issue, could you make a jsfiddle for me?

Comment: @LukeXF Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/reothenew/uzxf2c3q/). Took a while to replay cause our time zones are probably different. So the "rogue" link is for the first frame (red colour) and the "listen" link is for the second frame (black colour). Without the javascript the links work. With it they don't.

Answer (score 0):

In your css `a:active` 'active', in this case is a psuedo-class not a regular selector class, which styles a link which is being clicked on. It is not the same as 'a.active' which is what you get when you call `$('a').addClass("active")` so you will not see any effect from the css you currently have.

So if what you are doing is trying to add / remove an 'active' selector class just change your css to:

`a.active {
text-decoration: underline;
}`

also you should reformat your html as LukeXF suggested.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I can't seem to make it work with a.active either. I tried adding on the javascript code into the html mentioned by Luke as well, but that combination also didn't work.